# Why doesn't WebRTC work with Symmetric NAT?

Tags: webrtc, nat, nat-traversal

Let's say we have two peers - A & B - trying to establish a WebRTC peer connection through Symmetric NAT. They exchanged the ICE candidates via signalling.

A's public address: **IP_A : Port_A**
B's public address: **IP_B : Port_B**

First, A tries to connect to B
**IP_A : Port_A  --->  IP_B : Port_B**

The request is however rejected by B's NAT. Only B's STUN server can connect B at that address.

Next it's B's turn.
**IP_B : Port_B  --->  IP_A : Port_A**

But here, shouldn't the connection be established? Because, Peer A's NAT table should have registered Peer B's address when A first sent request to B. So, any response from B must be accepted. But of course, it doesn't seem to work. So, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself. Symmetric NAT is even more restrictive than I thought. Look at the Wikipedia explanation,

> **Symmetric NAT**
>
> - Each request from the same internal IP address and port to a specific destination IP address and port is mapped to a unique
>   external source IP address and port; if the same internal host sends a
>   packet even with the same source address and port but to a different
>   destination, a different mapping is used.
> - Only an external host that receives a packet from an internal host can send a packet back.

The problem is, Symmetric NAT will use a different **IP : Port** combination for Peer A while sending a request to Peer B than the **IP_A : Port_A** combination provided by the STUN. But Peer B's remote description still points to **IP_A : Port_A**. So, the addresses don't match and connection never happens. Perhaps a port prediction system could still make this work I assume :D

Answer (score 0):

It makes a lot more sense if you think in terms of Mapping/Filtering. The other NAT terms don't do a good job of describing how things actually work. My answer comes from [RFC 4787](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4787) and [WebRTC for the Curious: Connecting](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/)

Mapping is when your NAT allocates a IP/Port for an outbound packet. A remote peer can the send traffic to this mapping. Filtering are the rules around who can use these mappings.

Filtering and Mappings can then be address dependent and independent. If a mapping is address dependent it means a new mapping is created for each time you contact a new IP/Port. If a mapping is address independent it means it is re-used no matter where you send traffic. These same rules apply to filtering.

---

To your original question it looks like address dependent mapping+filtering is causing an issue!

I would still expect things to work in the setup you describe. WebRTC has `Peer Reflexive Candidates`. WebRTC can discoverer new candidates during ICE connectivity checks. Since ICE is authenticated we can accept traffic from IP/Ports that haven't been exchanged, we just need to assert the ICE userfragment and password is what we expect.